# Random variables over large measurable cardinals

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

This question assumes the existence of a large real-valued measurable cardinal. Let $X$ be an uncountable set and $(X,2^X)$ equipped with a non-atomic probability distribution $P$. Additionally, let $Q$ be the "uniform" distribution on the set $\{0,1\}^X$ --- i.e., the product of independent Bernoulli(1/2)
random variables indexed by $X$ --- whose existence follows from the
Łomnicki-Ulam theorem. The $\sigma$-algebra for the latter probability space is the usual cylindrical one used for random processes.

Let us now draw a "random function" $h\sim Q$
and a random point $x\sim P$.

Question: Is the object $h(x)$ a measurable random
variable on the corresponding product space?

Comment: Do you mean that $X$ carries a nonatomic total measure?

Comment: Yes, a nonatomic total probability measure.

Comment: I think that the fact that $X$ is real-valued-measurable doesn't help.  I think the measure space you're describing is just the Lebesgue measure on binary $X$-sequences.

Comment: So we can do Vitali's argument to show there's a nonmeasurable set and thus $h$ might not be a measurable function.  Let $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb N \}$ be a sequence of distinct elements of $X$.  For binary $X$-sequences $f,g$, say $f \sim g$ iff there is a finite $s \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $f$ is the result of flipping the bits of $g$ on $\{ x_n : n \in s \}$.  Each $s$ induces a measure-preserving transformation, corresponding to translation in $\mathbb R$.  Each equivalence class is countable, and you know the rest...

Comment: @MonroeEskew I think your description of "Lebesgue measure on binary sequences" applies to the uniform measure on {0,1}^X with its cylindrical sigma-algebra but not to (X,2^X). I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.